# 0curl: (7) Failed to connect to hooks.slack.com port 443: Connexion refused

Tags: git, slack, post-update

I am trying to send message in slack channel from my post-update hook git with this code :

```
#!/bin/bash
#echo "********* Notification Slack *********"
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"Hello, World!"}' 
https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXX/xxx/xxxxxx
```

I have this error :

```
0curl: (7) Failed to connect to hooks.slack.com port 443: Connexion refused to ssh://ssh..../hub.git
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you think this is a git problem?

Comment: Is `https://...` on a new line? that would not work. Must be part of the same line as `curl`